# SQL - working with arrays

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

I'm fairly new to SQL but have to write some queries in BigQuery at work. I have a query that joins different tables and gives me a following output:

[image: account_ids with is_subscriber column]

The goal is to figure out which users (account_ids) have ever been subscribers and create a column that will say yes (if at least one 'y') or no (if all 'n').

How to write a query where I can create a new column where: for each account_id if there is at least one ‘y’ in is_subsc then it will show ‘yes’, if there is no ‘y’ associated with that account_id it will return ‘no’ 
So for the table above it would be:

```
account_id ------------------------------------------------is_subscriber
1632bfb5-c294-4282-b3fb-a73061dc475a--------no 
ef568b94-e621-4c36-b8da-ede623051da7--------no
6f60e841-9b60-49c9-a36f-70fc00d40f4a---------yes
ec68a446-3a7d-42fc-a79f-a71446b897cd--------yes
```

I’d appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one method:

```
select account_id,
       (select max(is_sub)
        from unnest(is_subs) is_sub
       ) as ever_sub
from t;
```

This uses the observation that `'y'` is bigger than `'n'`, so `max()` works for this encoding and your purpose.  In general, though, I would recommend storing such flags as *bona fide* booleans, rather than characters.

Answer (score 1):

Another option for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT account_id, 
  ('y' IN UNNEST(is_subs)) is_ever_subscribed
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

If to apply to dummy data from your question as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '1632bfb5-c294-4282-b3fb-a73061dc475a' account_id, ['n'] is_subs UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ef568b94-e621-4c36-b8da-ede623051da7', ['n'] UNION ALL
  SELECT '6f60e841-9b60-49c9-a36f-70fc00d40f4a', ['n', 'n', 'y'] UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ec68a446-3a7d-42fc-a79f-a71446b897cd', ['y', 'n'] 
)
SELECT account_id, 
  ('y' IN UNNEST(is_subs)) is_ever_subscribed
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

result will be as

```
Row     account_id                              is_ever_subscribed   
1       1632bfb5-c294-4282-b3fb-a73061dc475a    false    
2       ef568b94-e621-4c36-b8da-ede623051da7    false    
3       6f60e841-9b60-49c9-a36f-70fc00d40f4a    true     
4       ec68a446-3a7d-42fc-a79f-a71446b897cd    true
```

If your output a must be `y/n` vs. `true/false` you can use below version

```
#standardSQL
SELECT account_id, 
  IF('y' IN UNNEST(is_subs), 'y', 'n') is_ever_subscribed
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

in this case  - output will be

```
Row     account_id                              is_ever_subscribed   
1       1632bfb5-c294-4282-b3fb-a73061dc475a    n    
2       ef568b94-e621-4c36-b8da-ede623051da7    n    
3       6f60e841-9b60-49c9-a36f-70fc00d40f4a    y    
4       ec68a446-3a7d-42fc-a79f-a71446b897cd    y
```